# Binding a textbox to two fields

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm actually running into an issue I would like to resolve, preferably, without code behind.

I have a textbox binded to a string which can be updated every 50 millisecond and I would like to, if I click on it and enter a new string, it updates `TargetExample` in my class. I've heard about multibinding but I'm not sure it does what I want and I've also thought about hiding the textbox by clicking on it and showing another one to edit but I wanted to know if there is another way.

```
    private string sourceExample;
    public string SourceExample
    {
        get { return sourceExample; }
        set
        {
            sourceExample= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SourceExample");
        }
    }

    private string targetExample;
    public string TargetExample
    {
        get { return targetExample; }
        set
        {
            targetExample= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TargetExample");
        }
    }
```

in the XAML File :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SourceExample}">
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the same property for both ways and on PropertyChanged get the new string by comparing or some operation like that?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @ViVi The textbox is contained in a datatemplate that is binded to an observablecollection of my class. The textbox is supposed to display values retrieved from a machine connected to the computer and can be refreshed every millisecond, but sometimes a user want to write a value into the machine on the selected textbox. It has to be fast so I'm not sure about using this way

Comment: What happens (or is intended) when : the user clicks the textbox; starts to edit text; and the string is updated from the machine?
Do you want it to ignore machine updates while editing?

Comment: Setting the same value from two sources, from the user's input and from a remote machine, is a [race condition](https://www.google.com/search?q=race+condition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). You need to have two different UI controls for your `SourceExample` and `TargetExample`.

Comment: Yes. I agree with mechanic and Ginger Ninja because if you do that the functionality wont work properly. If the text box is updated every milli second, then how will the data entered by user be accepted by the machine? Just keep 2 text boxes if possible in any means.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer but I used @mechanic answer, meaning that I used two textbox and played with their Visibility attribute. Thank you all for your answers